# cannot get resource "storageclasses" in API group "storage.k8s.io" at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I am trying to use storageclass, PersistentVolumeClaim ,PersistentVolume
I can run by command promt from local and working fine
But when deploying by azure pipeline getting issue
"cannot get resource "storageclasses" in API group "storage.k8s.io" at the cluster scope"

[image]

```
 kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
parameters:
  storageAccount: xxxdevxxx
  location: Souxxxxst xxxxx

---
# Create a Secret to hold the name and key of the Storage Account
# Remember: values are base64 encoded
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azurefile-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  azurestorageaccountname: YWlhZ7xxxxxzdA==
  azurestorageaccountkey: a2s4bURfghfhjxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxMUd6eE1UTEdxZHdRUzhvR09UZ0xBempPN3dXZEF0K1E9PQ==

---
# Create a persistent volume, with the corresponding StorageClass and the reference to the Azure File secret.
# Remember: Create the share in the storage account otherwise the pods will fail with a "No such file or directory"
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jee-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: azurefile
  azureFile:
    secretName: azurefile-secret
    shareName: jee-log
    readOnly: false
  mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000

---
# Create a PersistentVolumeClaim referencing the StorageClass and the volume
# Remember: this is a static scenario. The volume was created in the previous step.
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jee-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce  
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: azurefile-xxxx
  volumeName: jee-pv
```

Comment: The error you included indicates that service account *aia-pms* does not have sufficient privileges in the cluster scope. Please include ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding for this service account.

Comment: @p10l that should be an Answer - I'd vote for it

Comment: @p10l I ll try to add clusteRrole and clusterRoleBinding

Comment: @p10l  Actually when i apply from my local command prompt its working without role 
But i am trying this from azure pipeline release - in this case azure pipeline service account  not getting access , can you help me out this scenario

Comment: When you issue changes from command line, most of the time you are using privileged user (unless your administrator customized the cluster to change that behavior). To check if *aia-pms* has sufficient privileges use `kubectl auth can-i list storageclasses --as=system:serviceaccount:aia-pms --all-namespaces`

Comment: kubectl auth can-i list storageclasses --as=system:serviceaccount:aia-pms --all-namespaces
This result gives me no

Comment: @p10l When i changed pipeline Kubernetes service connection to Kubernetes recourse manager - it started working without any Cluster role

Comment: That's great! If you found a working solution, please post it as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Azurepipeline to create persistance volume and storage class by Kubernetes
use **Service connection type** = **Azure Resource Manager** instead of **Azure service connection**